# Regex: how to change this regex to make it support both formats

Tags: regex

Currently, this pattern `'[a-z]+([a-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*'` will accept string like `abc_def`, but I want it to accept string like `com.google` too, is it possible to do that. Sorry, I'm not familiar with regex.

The context is this regex is from lint package name rule and it rejects package name with a dot inside.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
'[a-z]+([a-z][A-Za-z0-9._]*)*'
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `[a-z]+` | any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(` | group and capture to \1 (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)): |
| `[a-z]` | any character of: 'a' to 'z' |
| `[A-Za-z0-9._]*` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9', '.', '_' (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)*` | end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a quantifier on this capture, only the LAST repetition of the captured pattern will be stored in \1) |

Comment: Thanks for this. And I do will take some time to learn this tech later. And also thank you for whom close my question, at least I know there was an answer there though I didn't find it.